# Como verificar se o registo existe na base de dados e actualizar caso exista

Tags: mysql, sql

Como verificar se o registo existe na base de dados e actualizar caso exista
Eu tentei desta forma

```
Select if((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Pessoas WHERE id = 0) > 0, 
          ( UPDATE Pessoas SET Name ="João" where id = 0 ),
          ( INSERT INTO Pessoas VALUES (0,"João")  )
);
```

Comment: Só esclareça uma coisinha: no `if` vc faz uma busca com `id = 2` e no `update` e `insert` vc atribui o `id` `0`. Isso me deixou um pouco confuso...

Comment: Corrigi agora obrigado

Comment: Ok, vou formular uma resposta.

Comment: Porque todas as respostas estão com negativo?

Comment: Também não entendi.

Comment: Porque é que agora a minha pergunta tambem tem negativo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalmente para esses casos eu recorro ao *stored procedure* para realizar essas operações de controle, por ex:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE 'gravar_pessoas'(zid int, znome varchar(100))
begin
   if not exists(select * from pessoas where id = zid) then
     insert into pessoas() values(zid, znome);
   end if;

   if exists(select *  from pessoas where id = zid) then
      update pessoas set nome = znome where id = zid;
    end if;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Me soa estranho antes da consulta você já ter o `id` e, ainda assim, verificar se ele existe no banco de dados. Mas vamos à resposta!</strike>

---

Considerando que você já tem o `id` do registro a ser buscado e que `id` **quase sempre** é uma chave primária ou única, você pode rodar a seguinte *query*:

```
INSERT INTO `pessoas` (`id`, `Name`) VALUES (0, 'João') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Name` = 'João';
```

É exatamente o que você está fazendo na *query* da sua pergunta:

**Se** existe algum registro com o `id = 0`, atualize seu `Name = 'João'`.

**Se não**, insira o `id = 0` com `Name = 'João'`.

Comment: Ao colega que saiu dando -1 em TUDO aqui: poderia, por favor, deixar um comentário esclarecendo o que não está de acordo?!

Answer (score -2):

```
select if((select count(*) from Pessoas where id = 2) > 0, 
(UPDATE Pessoas SET Name ="João" where id = 0), 
INSERT INTO Pessoas VALUES (0,"João")) as value from Pessoas
```

Comment: As pessoas que deram -1 poderiam esclarecer o porque ?

Comment: tambem não sei porque so queria mesmo saber a melhor resolução para o meu problema